# SQL right join with functional condition

Tags: sql, subquery, right-join

I have such join:

```
             "SELECT ADB.column1, BDB.column2 FROM ADB RIGHT JOIN BDB ON  
        (SELECT SUBSTRING( ADB.column1, LEN(ADB.column1) - 
     CHARINDEX('|',REVERSE(ADB.column1)) + 2  ,
 LEN(ADB.column1)  ) FROM BDB) = BDB.column2", sqlCon);
```

When I run this code I get error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Subquery returned more than 1
>   value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= ,
>
> > , >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.'

How can I force subquery to get only 1 data per row ?

Comment: So which part of the error message do you not understand?

Comment: Which dbms?  SQL is just a language use by many dbms vendors.  Each vendor has their own syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you query will be like below

```
SELECT ADB.column1,
         BDB.column2 FROM
        ADB RIGHT JOIN BDB ON  
            ( SUBSTRING( ADB.column1, LEN(ADB.column1) - 
         CHARINDEX('|',REVERSE(ADB.column1)) + 2  ,
     LEN(ADB.column1) ) 
       ) = BDB.column2
```

you are joining ADB and BDB but on join condition used select from BDB which does not make any sense

Comment: You are right Sir! my mistake. Too complicated query, I've shown only part of it for simplicity. Thank you very much for perfect answer!

Comment: Just did it. There is time interval which you have to wait , till you may mark answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Seem you did confuse yourself... You don't need to subselect `FROM BDB` since you have all those `ADB.column1` transformations.

```
SELECT ADB.column1, BDB.column2 
FROM ADB 
RIGHT JOIN BDB 
ON  SUBSTRING(ADB.column1, LEN(ADB.column1) - 
       CHARINDEX('|',REVERSE(ADB.column1)) + 2  ,
       LEN(ADB.column1)
    ) = BDB.column2
```